# How to delete rows between specific column values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with the following structure

```
time <- c(0,"start",200,300,"end", 500)
c1 <- c(3.1, "start", 4.5, 4.1, "end", 3.5)
c2 <- c(4.4, "start", 4.5, 4.1, "end", 4.8)
df <- data.frame(time, c1, c2)
```

I am trying to remove the rows including and between 2 and 5. The final data.frame would then be:

```
time  c1   c2
0     3.1  4.4
500   3.5  4.8
```

start and end strings occur throughout the data frame and they are random. I tried shift function however no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming for every "start" there would be an "end" you can create a sequence between those indices and remove them :

```
start <- which(df$time == 'start')
end <- which(df$time == 'end')
df[-unlist(mapply(`:`, start, end)), ]

#  time  c1  c2
#1    0 3.1 4.4
#6  500 3.5 4.8
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I now find out about mapply and unlist and how they can be used together in data.frame manipulation.